# Terraform localstack for aws elasticsearch not creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, localstack

I am using Terraform [localstack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/elasticsearch/#custom-endpoints) for Terraform unit(modules) testing instead of testing in actual AWS infra.

**Terraform Configuration**:

`main.tf file`: https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/b59294e7b8c9bcc33426addcd980078e

`terraform.tfvars file`: https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/ae538d3a96ea6c10030e6263be60e2a1

`provider_override.tf file`: https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/a760260c3ed3d10ebc3dbccb965ef558

`Problem`:
Usually, on AWS infra, it takes less than 15min to create with the above terraform configuration but **localstack** is not creating even after 40min

[image]

But using aws cli same [localstack](https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/elasticsearch/) able to create elasticsearch in 10min

`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name my-domain`

Please share if you know any fix or working example.

`Terraform Version`: v0.14.11

`Terraform AWS Provider Version`: 3.45.0

`Localstack Version`: 0.13.3

`Localstack Logs`: https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/2d71dc72ee16db346ece620a46d22ace

`Terraform Logs`:
https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/770c0ba4ab72a1f3c0ce2a25f41d372e

Comment: You might want to run terraform with `TF_LOG=TRACE` to see what is really happening, would be helpful if you post the log here too.

Comment: Thankyou @JuanFontes Added logs with TF_LOG=trace here is it https://gist.github.com/sudhir6199/770c0ba4ab72a1f3c0ce2a25f41d372e

Comment: There is an error with your es policy, see `* "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z": parsing time "1641914481.19" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z": cannot parse "914481.19" as "-"`

Comment: @JuanFontes Thankyou i found the issue through the one you highlighted, its not json parse issue as am able to apply same without issue in actual aws, its some time conversion issue, seems localstack doesn't support latest terraform aws provider i.e. v3.71.0  I configured in terraform provider as = ">=3.45.0" so it was picking terraform aws provider v3.71.0 version now after I made it as = "=3.45.0" it worked and no pars issue, elasticsearch spawn in within 3-4min. great! :)

Answer (score 0):

localstack doesn't support latest terraform aws provider i.e. v3.71.0 in my provider config I mentioned = ">=3.45.0" so it was picking terraform aws provider v3.71.0 version now after I made it as = "=3.45.0" it worked, elasticsearch spawn in within 3-4min. great! :)